# How can I keep the leading zero's in my pdf generated documents from google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, mailmerge

I have created a google test form and test form response. In the response spreadsheet, I have written below script to capture the inputted values from the from > generate a pdf/doc > email the pdf & > save a copy of the doc in a target folder. The issue I'm running into is that the section labeled as passcode could start with a "0" or multiple "0's", which I have formatted in the script for the spreadsheet. However when it generates the PDF/DOC, the zero's are removed. Is there any way to keep the leading 0's when converted in the PDF/DOC?

```js
function formatNumber(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var cell = sheet.getRange("D2:D");
// Always show 4 digits
 cell.setNumberFormat("0000");
}
var docTemplate = "11laarf0ThJ4mANX4KzHZCblVwRgphlf-bCblaUMl4oc";
var docName = "Test Form";
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var email_address = "jimmy111@gmail.com";
var Time_Stamp = e.namedValues["Timestamp"];
var full_name = e.namedValues["Name"];
var phone = e.namedValues["Phone Number"];
var passcode = e.namedValues["Passcode"];
var price = e.namedValues["Price"];
var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(full_name+' '+docName)
.getId();
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDate', Time_Stamp);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyName', full_name);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPhone', phone);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyCode', passcode);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPrice', price);
  copyDoc.saveAndClose();
  var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");
  var subject = "CIR Testform for "+ full_name + "";
  var body = "Here is the registration form for "+ full_name +"";
  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
  var targetFolder = DocsList.getFolderById('0B-LfisIjjXtvLW82X3o1UzNyY1U');
  var file = DocsList.getFileById(copyId);
  file.addToFolder(targetFolder);
  file.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
}

function assignEditUrls() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('16zVePLm61yRsSZMaoDI5MWIeB-vGHZGEoR9J7uJ0CP8');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var urlCol = 6; // column number where URL's should be populated; A = 1, B = 2 etc
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
    urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
  }
  for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {

    resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j] [0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a workaround to this issue, it's less than ideal but it's working.

Using the Pre-Filled form feature, enter a period in each response that requires the leading zero.

So if your user had entered "0123456", the recorded response will appear as "0.123456" you can then use substring to remove the first two charecters.

e.g.

```
var phone = e.namedValues["Phone Number"].substring(2);
```

This will then give you the leading zero. The only issue is accidental deletion of the period from the pre-filled form, although you can set a validation which checks for it, and then an error asking the user to enter it if they've removed it.

Not pretty, but we're up and running with that now at least.

Comment: Your current answer is an answer, but your original answer was not; it was a question. Please do not post questions as answers.